# doesn't reload httpd.conf in Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-linux

How Can I reflect a modification in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ?

I am in trouble... Apache in EC2 does not work well.

My Amzon linux Version is here

```
$  cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
```

```
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

so I t checked the status.

```
$ systemctl status httpd.service
```

status is here

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since  2021-05-10
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 2971 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2971 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

 5月 10 13:00:00 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal httpd[2971]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/stackflow/public] does not exist
```

I noticed
DocumentRoot [/var/www/stackflow/public]  is wrong path...

I modified

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/stackoverflow/public">
    AllowOverride all
   #Require all denied
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

```
$ sudo systemctl reload httpd.service
```

```
Job for httpd.service invalid.
```

changes seems not be reflected.

Comment: Could you update your question to include: (1) the OS on your EC2 instance (Ubuntu/RedHat/Debian/Etc.) (2) the last 25 lines of your Apache error log (probably in `/var/log/apache2` or similar). This will make it easier to offer specific advice 

Comment: $ cat /var/log/apache2 
cat: /var/log/apache2: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@ip-x-y-z-a www]$ cd /var/log/apache2 
-bash: cd: /var/log/apache2: No such file or directory

Comment: somehow I couldn't seem to find Any apache logs...

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/simplifying-apache-server-logs-with-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights/ suggests that the logs might be under `/var/log/www/error` and `/var/log/www/access` respectively (unless of course you changed that, too, in your httpd.conf.

Comment: umm I could neither find  logs in /var/log/www/error nor /var/log/www/access.